# Using generics "super" in implements/extends part of a class declaration

Tags: java, generics

I have the following declarations:

```
public interface Event<K> {}
public interface DataEvent<K, D> extends Event<K> {}
public interface OriginatedEvent<K, O> extends Event<K> {}

public class ErrorEvent<O, E extends Throwable> implements OriginatedEvent<Class<? extends ErrorEvent<O, E>>, O>, DataEvent<Class<? extends ErrorEvent<O, E>>, E> {}

public interface EventHandler<K, E extends Event<K>> {

public abstract class AbstractEventErrorHandler<O, E extends ErrorEvent<O, ? extends Throwable>> implements EventHandler<Class<E>, E> {}
```

I get this: `Bound mismatch: The type E is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends Event<K>> of the type EventHandler<K,E>`

on the last part `implements EventHandler<Class<E>, E> {}`

If I change: `public abstract class AbstractEventErrorHandler<O, E extends ErrorEvent<O, ? extends Throwable>> implements EventHandler<Class<E>, E> {}`
and: `public interface EventHandler<K, E extends Event<? super K>>`

to: `public abstract class AbstractEventErrorHandler<O, E extends ErrorEvent<O, ? super Throwable>> implements EventHandler<Class<E>, E> {}`
and: `public interface EventHandler<K, E extends Event<K>>`

it no longer has the error (but I get other problems later on, see below). I tried to find documentation on this to better design my generics and understand why it is doing this but I could not find anything useful, people either talk about using extends/super in a method parameter or only extends in a class/interface signature, any mention of super in a class/interface signature is just to say it is not allowed in the 1st part of the declaration. In my case I don't use it in the declaration part of the signature but in the inheritance part.

I had a look at PECS? (Producer Extends, Consumer Super) but this seems valid for method declarations; in the class/interface it could be used as either later on in the code.

Can someone please explain or point me to a good explanation?

If I change it like I mentioned above and try to use my AbstractEventErrorHandler class like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractEventBusErrorHandler extends AbstractEventErrorHandler<LocalEventBus, ErrorEvent<LocalEventBus, EventBusException>> {}
```

and it gives me:
`Bound mismatch: The type ErrorEvent<LocalEventBus, EventBusException> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <E extends ErrorEvent<O,? super Throwable>> of the type AbstractEventErrorHandler<O,E>?`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just got your generic types wrong.

<strike>Instead of</strike>

```
public abstract class AbstractEventErrorHandler< O, E extends ErrorEvent<O, ? extends Throwable>> implements EventHandler<Class<E>, E> {}
```

you might want to use

```
public abstract class AbstractEventErrorHandler<O, E extends ErrorEvent<O, ? extends Throwable>> implements EventHandler<Class<O>, E> {}
```

The problem is that `EventHandler` expects the first type `Class<E>` to be the first type of `ErrorEvent` which is `Class<O>` due to `ErrorEvent` implementing the interfaces with `Class<K>`.

Btw, you should try and stick to one name per type, i.e. switching from `K` to `O` might have caused some confusion.

**UPDATE:**

I reread your question and I think I missed a definition when I copied your code to my IDE for testing. So scrap the above.

I fact, it seems to be easier than the above:

You declared `ErrorEvent` to implement both `OriginatedEvent` and `DataEvent` with the first type containing a wildcard: `Class<? extends ErrorEvent<O, E>`

Those wildcards are always resolved to different types, so the compiler gets confused when trying to resolve the `implements EventHandler<Class<E>, E>` on the last line (`Class<E>` can only match one of the wildcards and thus the other doesn't match).

To resolve this, you'd need to introduce a type for the wildcards, e.g.:

```
public class ErrorEvent<O, E extends Throwable, K extends ErrorEvent<O, E, ?>>  
   implements OriginatedEvent<Class<K>, O>, DataEvent<Class<K>, E> {}
```

Then in your error handler you declare that `K` to be `E`:

```
public abstract class AbstractEventErrorHandler<O, E extends ErrorEvent<O, ? extends Throwable, E>> implements EventHandler<Class<E>, E> {}
```

Comment: That and the EventHandler interface (`public interface EventHandler<K, E extends Event<? super K>> {}`), thanks!

Comment: Nope, scratch that, I wrote that too fast. It was just the EventHandler interface, so I am unacepting the answer. Also I still don't understand the "why" part.

Comment: @Gabriel you're right, I got a misconception there and updated the answer.

Comment: Thomas (for some reason if I put @ in front your name gets removed), ok, I see what you mean, this is a way of doing it indeed, thanks. I will mark the question answered, thanks. Do you know why it also works when I change the event handler to `public interface EventHandler<K, E extends Event<? super K>> {}`?

Comment: @Gabriel my name with the @ is removed since it's my answer and thus I get notified anyways ;) - I'm currently not able to wrap my head around this but I'll try and look it up in the specification.